# How to get the Index of Max element in UInt Vec , Chisel

Tags: chisel

I'm trying to get the index of the Max element in a UInt vector.
My code looks like this

```
val pwr = Vec.tabulate(N) {i => energyMeters(i).io.pwr}
val maxPwr = pwr.indexOf(pwr.max)
```

However this code generate compilation error:

```
No implicit Ordering Defined for Chisel.UInt.
val maxPwr = pwr.indexOf(pwr.max)
                             ^
```

I understand that I probably need to implement the max function , can someone give an example how this should be done ?

Edit:
I also tried this:

```
val pwr = Vec.tabulate(N) {i => energyMeters(i).io.pwr}
val maxPwr = pwr reduceLeft {(x,y) => Mux(x > y,x,y)}
val maxPwridx = pwr.indexOf(maxPwr)
```

But it fails on elaboration , when I tried to cast maxPwridx to UInt.
I've ended up with this workaround:

```
val pwr = Vec.tabulate(N) {i => energyMeters(i).io.pwr}
val maxPwr = pwr reduceLeft {(x,y) => Mux(x > y,x,y)}
val maxPwridx = pwr.indexWhere((x : UInt => x === maxPwr))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chisel's `Vec` extends Scala's `Seq`. This means that a `Vec` has *both* dynamic access hardware methods that will allow you to generate hardware to search for something in a `Vec` (e.g., `indexWhere`, `onlyIndexWhere`, `lastIndexWhere`) as well as all the methods available to normal Scala sequences (e.g., `indexOf`).

For the purposes of doing hardware operations, you want to use the former (as you found in your last edit---which looks great!) as opposed to the latter.

To get some handle on this, the screenshot below shows the Chisel 3.3.0-RC1 API documentation for `VecLike`, filtered to excluded inherited methods. Notable here are `indexWhere`, `onlyIndexWhere`, `lastIndexWhere`, `exists`, `forall`, and `contains`:

[image: Output of VecLike documentation filtered to only methods added in VecLike]

And the documentation for `Vec`. The only interesting method here would be `reduceTree`:

[image]